# Set matplotlib legend markersize to a constant

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

I'm making a diagram using matplotlib, and it has plt.Circles and plt.axvlines to represent different shapes. I need a legend to describe these shapes, but the problem is the legend marker (the image part), changes size depending on the input, which looks awful. How do I set the size to a constant?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6.4, 6), dpi=200, frameon=False)
ax = fig.gca()
# 3 Circles, they produce different sized legend markers
ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((0,0), radius=1, alpha=0.9, zorder=0, label="Circle"))
ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((-1,0), radius=0.05, color="y", label="Point on Circle"))
ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((1, 0), radius=0.05, color="k", label="Opposite Point on Circle"))
# A vertical line which produces a huge legend marker
ax.axvline(0, ymin=0.5-0.313, ymax=0.5+0.313, linewidth=12, zorder=1, c="g", label="Vertical Line")
ax.legend(loc=2)
ax.set_xlim(-2,1.2) # The figsize and limits are meant to preserve the circle's shape
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
fig.show()
```

I've seen solutions including legend.legendHandles[0]._size or various assortments of that, and it doesn't seem to change the size regardless of the value I set

Answer (score 1):

The legend markers for the circles are different in size because the first circle has no edgecolor, while the two other ones have an edgecolor set via `color`. You may instead set the facecolor of the circle. Alternatively, you can set the linewidth of all 3 circles equal.

The legend marker for the line is so huge because it simply copies the attribute from the line in the plot. If you want to use a different linewidth, you can update it via the respective legend handler.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D

def update_prop(handle, orig):
    handle.update_from(orig)
    handle.set_linewidth(2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6.4, 6), dpi=200, frameon=False)

# 3 Circles, set the facecolor instead of edge- and face-color
ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((0,0), radius=1, alpha=0.9, zorder=0, label="Circle"))
ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((-1,0), radius=0.05, facecolor="y", label="Point on Circle"))
ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((1, 0), radius=0.05, facecolor="k", label="Opposite Point on Circle"))

# Line, update the linewidth via 
ax.axvline(0, ymin=0.5-0.313, ymax=0.5+0.313, linewidth=12, zorder=1, c="g", label="Vertical Line")
ax.legend(loc=2, handler_map={plt.Line2D:HandlerLine2D(update_func=update_prop)})


ax.set_xlim(-2,1.2)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]